# Adding PublishingPageLayout to file via REST-api

Tags: publishing-page, rest

I am adding a file with the REST-API:

```
http://hostname/sites/site/news/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/site/news/Pages')/Files/add(url='new.aspx',overwrite=true)
```

How can I additionally add the PublishingPageLayout-property (and other properties) to the created page/file via REST-API?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried with the REST API, however via CSOM you would need to set the "PublishingPageLayout" to the Site Collection relative url of the actual ASPX representing the layout using something like  "/sites/mySiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/ArticleLeft.aspx, ArticleLeft" and at the same time the ContentTypeID property using the actual Content type Identifier.